# How do I add google calendars to online accounts on Odin?

Tags: calendar, release-odin

I'm trying to understand the whole online accounts thing. I got how to add gmail and other SMTP emails to online accounts, but I'm not having any luck with calendars. I've found [this](https://blog.mozilla.org/calendar/2013/09/google-is-changing-the-location-url-of-their-caldav-calendars/) about the CalDAV URL, but using

```
https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/your-email-address/events
```

as the CalDAV server gives me an error:

[image]

This is regardless if I use my gmail password or a unique app password.

Comment: A very similar question about using CalDAV was [asked on the Ubuntu Stack Exchange](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879229/how-to-sync-google-caldav-with-evolution-calendar) years ago and didn't get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using the old URL format (`https://www.google.com/calendar/dav/your-email-address/user/`, from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GoogleCalendarWithEvolution)), I was able to connect and Online Accounts could retrieve the list of calendars.

Calendar was open and it crahed with this message,

[image]

But then I opened it again and it worked properly.

After reboot, Wingpanel always crahes after clicking the date unless I open Calendar before and wait for all calendars to load.

Tasks don't seem to be working, though. Trying to add task to the newly-added account results in a `Password not found` error.

Honestly, I'm a bit disappointed in all this. It is a PITA to set up and even after setup it doesn't seem to really work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

According to Google's [developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/caldav/v2/guide) page, that url you're using is the correct one. Although they also mention this one:

`https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/calid/user`

And as far as I can tell, the `calid` is your email address with the "@" replaced with a "%40", like `john%40gmail.com`. But I haven't been able to get it to work with these settings either.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are just concerned with understand more about the Online Accounts tools, but in case your concern is to make the calendar work, my answer would go as below:

I was having problems synchronizing with my Google Calendar, but a guy on Reddit helped me solve it. When we are at the Odin Elementary Calendar we tend to click on the configuration button and then click on online accounts configuration to synchronize things, but in that way, I couldn't do the synchronization.

So, a guy on Reddit showed me how we actually can go into "add new calendar" and there will be a "Google" option, which should work. Here is the screenshot link he sent to me showing it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqk7A.jpg

I hope this addresses your concerns. I wasn't able to make Google Calendar work with CalDav too, only with Vivaldi Calendar, but as I was having time configuration problems with it (Vivaldi Calendar), I just did what I did with Google configuration.

Source:

https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/p3ltml/how_to_add_google_calendar_to_the_calendar_app/h8rxz9w/?context=3

Comment: Thanks, I already knew about this particular way of importing calendars. But I was trying to use the new tool, which I gather is the way forward.